# Site recommendation to ask a question on disputed answer

Tags: discussion, site

I know the difference between [ELL](https://ell.stackexchange.com/) and [ELU](https://english.stackexchange.com/) sites. However, when it comes to some questions I am confused on where to ask them.

Which is the site to ask the below question?

> Does the following statement agree with the views of the writer in given passage?
>   You have to answer,
>
> - True: *If the statement agrees with the writer*
> - False: *If the state does not agree with the writer*
> - Not given: *if there is no information about this in the passage*
>
> Statement: **Guitar was used in rock and roll from the 1940s.**
>
> Passage:
>
> **In the earliest rock and roll styles of the late 1940s and early 1950s, either the piano or saxophone was often the lead instrument, but these were generally replaced or supplemented by guitar in the middle to late 1950s.**
>
> According to the tutor, the answer is **FALSE** but I think the answer to this question should actually be **NOT GIVEN**. The passage says guitar generally became the LEAD instrument in the 1950s, It DOES NOT SAY clearly whether guitars were used in 1940s or not. Hence the answer should be **NOT GIVEN**.
>
> Which is the correct answer?

Comment: I'd say **not given**, too. Most tests are stupid.

Comment: I would have said ELL is more appropriate, but it's a little too late now that you've already asked it here...If you're going to ask on meta, you should give the community more time to respond.

Comment: @Laurel Sure, Thank you for the recommendation . I had asked this question on https://meta.stackexchange.com/ originally, But someone deleted the question siting that it should be asked in this meta site.  I asked it here and as I got an *answer* to the actual question from the first comment I thought I will ask the question in English SE site. :)

Comment: I deleted that question and moved to ELL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is actually an on-topic question for this site. If all questions were as well formulated, users wouldn't be closing so many off-topic questions.

Here we have only "one" question. We have context. And the OP clearly explains why he is confused.  The OP also provides the answer supplied by the teacher/book. What more can one ask?

Yes, there will always be someone who turns up their nose at an IELTS, TOEFL, or GRE question because... they are native speakers and believe exams are inadequate tools for measuring one's writing and speaking ability in English,  and some (or most) believe that exam questions are misleading, or worse, plain stupid.

But English exams are a reality and passing them a necessity for thousands of candidates all over the world. Obtaining the best possible grade is hugely important for candidates who wish to take a Masters in an English speaking country,  or who wish to find work abroad in the US or Australia.  We should do everything we can to help these users who ask **on-topic questions**, these users are, after all,  among the most motivated we will ever meet up with.

Related:

1. [Does this stackoverflow forum answer questions related to IELTS?](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7200/does-this-stackoverflow-forum-answer-questions-related-to-ielts)
2. [Does the massive edit to "Playing sports - does swimming count?" really "clarfiy the English question"? If so, for whom?](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10310/does-the-massive-edit-to-playing-sports-does-swimming-count-really-clarfiy)
3. [How does the community feel about exam or IELTS questions](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10338/how-does-the-community-feel-about-exam-or-ielts-questions)
4. [Are GRE questions a good fit for the site?](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6901/are-gre-questions-a-good-fit-for-the-site)
5. [Are GRE verbal questions not welcomed in this site?](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2819/are-gre-verbal-questions-not-welcomed-in-this-site)

Comment: Thank you, I have asked this question on ELL. I would like to know what do you think about it. 

https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/134301/correct-answer-from-options-true-false-and-not-given

Comment: @Vinod I've left a comment. Hope it helps.

Comment: +1 My thoughts, exactly. I was about to post the same idea, actually.

Answer (score 2):

This is a 'test of comprehension' question and ought to be on-topic on both ELU (english.stackexchange.com) and ELL as long as you don't specify that it is an *examination* question, which does seem to create a bit of confusion as in 'what would be the *expected* answer?' I would suggest it is an English Learner's question and therefore better suited for ELL, but I see from your comment that you have (asked it at ELU, deleted it and) asked it on ELL already! So it is clear you have in effect answered your own *meta* question.

Comment: Why not specify that it is an examination question?

Comment: @NVZ do you remember all the controversy associated with some IELTS questions we got last month?  "How do I answer in IELTS when examiner asks, 'do you play sports?' I am a swimmer but swimming is not the type of sport you 'play', etc" MANY senior members at ELU seem to disapprove because examination questions often have 'expected answers' which possibly do not reflect actual usage, and a question about such exam questions is apparently 'not about the English language but about an exam,' as someone put it: I would refer you to some recent *meta* discussions on this topic, search keyword IELTS.